# Change Options for the AVR Programmer via Arduino IDE

Tags: avrdude, avr, programmer

I want to program an ATtiny through the Arduino IDE. I have a somehow strange programmer. But I can upload via avrdude by

> avrdude -p attiny13 -P /dev/cu.usbmodemfa131     -c stk500v2    -F -B20 -U flash:w:programm.hex

It took a while to figure out that I had to slow the baud rate via the -B20 switch. If I try to upload via the arduino 1.0.5 IDE avrdude is executed as follows.

> /Applications/Adafruit Arduino 1.0.5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Adafruit Arduino 1.0.5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -pattiny13 -cstk500v1 -P/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131 -Uflash:w:/var/folders/9t/5jldfq752fs1x74_rhn2plz80000gn/T/build7680201613426497544.tmp/attinytest.cpp.hex:i

My question is, how can I change the preferences such that I have control over the avrdude parameters? Say I want to add a -B20 switch and change stk500v1 to stk500v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: I'm afraid you can't do it with Arduino IDE 1.0.5.

**Long answer**:

First of all, be aware that `-B20` does not specify the baud rate but the bitclock period (in us); this is specific to `stk500v2` programmer.

Normally, enabling your programmer should only be a matter of adding it to the list of programmers known by Arduino IDE; that list can be found in `hardware/arduino/programmers.txt`. You would then append the following lines at the end of this file:

```
strangeprogrammer.name=Somehow Strange Programmer
strangeprogrammer.communication=serial
strangeprogrammer.protocol=stk500v2
strangeprogrammer.force=true
strangeprogrammer.speed=?????
```

However, the problem here is that Arduino IDE does not seem to be able to use flag `-B` (bitclock period) but only flag `-b` (baud rate) which value is set to whatever you will put to `strangeprogrammer.speed`.

At least that's what I could find out by inspecting Arduino IDE source code: `AvrdudeUploader.java` never adds that flag to the `avrdude` command-line :-(

That means your options are:

1. Rebuild the Arduino IDE 1.0 on your own after modifying `AvrdudeUploader.java` to support `-B` flag; code should be quite easy (about 2 more lines of Java code).
2. Switch to Arduino IDE 1.5 and follow [Federico's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/change-options-for-the-avr-programmer-via-arduino-ide/1077#1077) :-)
3. Use another IDE, something that deserves the **IDE** name. I use Eclipse with this [Arduino plugin](http://eclipse.baeyens.it/UsethePlugin.html) and it works fine for me. As a bonus, avrdude support seems better as you can see on the screenshot below:

[image]